# How to make cap deploy link my vendors folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I would like to link my vendor folder so I don't have 5 minutes down time every time  I deploy and have to run bundle install --deployment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Capistrano helped.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use a rake task after the capistrano deploy, [for example](http://ananelson.com/said/on/2007/12/30/remote-rake-tasks-with-capistrano/).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a new task to symlink vendor to the shared path and set it to run before `bundle:install`, but this is a little unnecessary - it'd be nicer to just bundle to the shared path in the first place instead of vendor.

If you're requiring and using 'bundler/capistrino' in your deploy.rb file, all you need to do is set `bundle_dir` and bundler will pick it up:

```
set :bundle_dir, File.join(fetch(:shared_path), 'bundle')
```

If you've written your own bundle task, set the variable as above, then use `--path #{fetch(:bundle_dir)}` in the task.